# Why is NilClass#to_hash lacking?

Tags: ruby, null

Various methods defined on `NilClass` are handy to avoid `Method undefined on NilClass` errors, and frees you from using `try`, `oror`, `andand`, `||`, `&&` in various occasions:

- **to_a** for multiple dimensioned array when there might not be some values for some indices:

  > array[i].to_a[j].to_a[k]
- **to_s** pattern match that might fail:

  > string[regex].to_s*2
- **to_i, to_f, to_c** for index search that might fail, etc:

  > array.index(element).to_i*3

But there is no `NilClass#to_hash` although there is `Hash#to_hash`.

If such method existed (`class NilClass; def to_hash; {} end end`), then we would be able to do:

- **to_hash** for multiple embedded hash when there might not be some values for some keys:

  > hash[:a].to_hash[:b].to_hash[:c]

The best alternative I can think of is:

```
hash.fetch(:a, {}).fetch(:b, {})[:c]
```

but it would be nice if we had `NilClass#to_hash`. Why is it missing?

Comment: Why is it missing? Because nobody in charge has added it. If this is a feature request, it's not really appropriate here. If this is a question about the mind of Matz, I think you won't get a definitive answer. You can add it yourself, if you like, to your code. *shrug* I'm not voting to close this question because perhaps someone will be able to come up with a really good argument why including this would make Ruby worse. My guess, however, is that there is not answer to the actual question you have asked.

Comment: It is not a feature request (yet). I was wondering because having it for array, string but not for hash looks asymmetric, and seemed it is intentional.

Comment: @Phrogz There seem to be some ruby developers on SO, if not for Matz, so I thought they might have an answer.

Comment: I wish you good luck in finding your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

I sent a request about `NilClass#to_hash` to ruby development. Matz rejected it shortly. Andrew notified me in the comment below that Matz gave a comment to it. Answer to the question is thus given my Matz, and you can see that by following Andrew's link below.

Comment: What do you mean by "without comment"? Matz provided a comment at http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/4621#note-3

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for checking that out and notifying me. I somehow missed the comment part. It was the first time I submitted to ruby-lang.org.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good point, and in Ruby, you can always monkeypatch such a method into nil, and the libraries in Rails do quite a bit of that kind of monkeypatching.  Personally, I try to avoid doing much of that, because altering the behavior of a widely-used class can have unforeseen side effects in other libraries.  If the patch is being performed by a popular framework, that's fine, because other libraries should have been tested with that, but doing it willy nilly is something else, altogether.

I'm thinking a `NilClass#to_hash` would exist by now, if that would address a pain point that a lot of folks were feeling.  The `try` syntax is not any longer, and not too horribly ugly.

```
hash.try(:[],a).try(:[],b).try(:[],c)
```

Comment: Note that `Object#try` is not part of standard Ruby, but a monkeypatch added by ActiveSupport for Rails.

Comment: My wonder is, I do think people are actually addressing a pain with that (I see lots questions on SO related to it), and still, there is no such method. I share your thoughts about that. Besides the fact that `try` is a rails method, I didn't like the fact that you have to turn the method into a symbol and give it as the first argument to `try`.

Comment: Yes, `Object#try` is part of ActiveSupport, but that doesn't mean it only works in Rails.  You can use ActiveSupport in any project.  See http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport .

Answer (score 0):

I would also be interested in a `NilClass#to_hash` method.

Here is the answer by Matz:

> to_a, etc. are explicit conversion methods, whereas to_int, to_hash,
>   etc. are implicit conversion methods.  I don't see any good reason to
>   add implicit conversion methods to nil.

Here is the question by Tsuyoshi Sawada:

> Various methods defined on `NilClass` are handy to avoid Method
>   undefined on  NilClass errors. For example,
>
> - `to_a` for multiple dimensioned array when there might not be some values for  some indices:
>
> array[i].to_a[j].to_a[k]
>
> - `to_s` for pattern match that might fail:
>
> string[regex].to_s*2
>
> - `to_i`, `to_f`, `to_c` for index search that might fail, etc:
>
> array.index(element).to_i*3
>
> But there is no `NilClass#to_hash` even though there is
>   `Hash#to_hash`. If such  method existed (equivalent to `class
>   NilClass; def to_hash; {} end end`), then  we would be able to do:
>
> - `to_hash` for multiple embedded hash when there might not be some values for  some keys:
>
> hash[:a].to_hash[:b].to_hash[:c]
>
> Is there any reason why `to_a`, `to_s`, `to_i`, `to_f`, `to_c` are all
>   defined  on `NilClass` but not for `to_hash`? If there is not, I would
>   like to request  this feature.

[Source](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1587004)